# Firebase Google Authentication not showing email address

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I'm working on Google Authentication in firebase however I was not able to access user email address through google authentication. i granted access for multiple user with one email address but it still doesn't work. I will get authenticated successfully but the email is null.Anyone has any idea why this is happening?

identifier(email address)
[image]